# ¿Por qué no me reconoce la clase creada?

Tags: java, class

```
// Este es el main

public class Ejercicio02Warren {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Proyect_mayuscula mayuscula = new Proyect_mayuscula();
    }
    
}

// Esta es la clase

package ejercicio02;

import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Proyect_mayuscula {
    
    String cadena01;
    String cadena02;
    String unionCadenas;
    String cadena;

    public Proyect_mayuscula(String cadena01, String cadena02, String unionCadenas,String cadena) {
        this.cadena01 = cadena01;
        this.cadena02 = cadena02;
        this.unionCadenas = unionCadenas;
        this.cadena = cadena;
    }
    
public void Cadenas(){
   
    cadena01 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite texto");
    cadena02 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el segundo texto");
    unionCadenas = cadena01 + cadena02;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,unionCadenas);
    cadena = unionCadenas.toUpperCase();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,cadena);
    
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que quiere decir que no la reconoce? que es lo que pasa?

Answer (score 2):

Eso es porque ya has definidos un constructor, que define que un objeto `Proyect_mayuscula` debe de ser creado con los parámetros `(String cadena01, String cadena02, String unionCadenas,String cadena)` :

```
public Proyect_mayuscula(String cadena01, String cadena02, String unionCadenas,String cadena) {
    this.cadena01 = cadena01;
    this.cadena02 = cadena02;
    this.unionCadenas = unionCadenas;
    this.cadena = cadena;
}
```

El constructor es el que define los requisitos para instanciar una clase, cuando en tu código instancias la clase `new Proyect_mayuscula()` estas llamando un constructor sin parámetros, el cual no tienes, para solventar el problema puedes tener uno o mas constructores si así lo necesitas, por defecto si no se especifica ningún constructor Java te define uno vacío, la solución crear un constructor vacío para que puedas instancias el objeto `new Proyect_mayuscula()`:

```
package ejercicio02;

import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Proyect_mayuscula {
    
    String cadena01;
    String cadena02;
    String unionCadenas;
    String cadena;

//Sobre carga del constructor
public Proyect_mayuscula() {
}

public Proyect_mayuscula(String cadena01, String cadena02, String unionCadenas,String cadena) {
        this.cadena01 = cadena01;
        this.cadena02 = cadena02;
        this.unionCadenas = unionCadenas;
        this.cadena = cadena;
 }
    
public void Cadenas(){
   
    cadena01 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite texto");
    cadena02 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el segundo texto");
    unionCadenas = cadena01 + cadena02;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,unionCadenas);
    cadena = unionCadenas.toUpperCase();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,cadena);
    
}
```